# setStreamMute method puts music player on normal speaker mode

Tags: android, performance

I came am facing weird situation while using  AudioManager.setStreamMute in KitKat version .
I want to make music player pause if someone makes call from my application,so I have used this method :

```
public void controlMusicPlayer(boolean state ) {

        Log.e("set music player ",""+state);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, state);

    }
```

Before user makes call I set it to true and after ending call I set it to false to its default setting. But when I installed app,made call,disconnected call,came out of application and start music player then song  must be played on loudspeaker mode but it is playing song on normal  speaker mode .If any one knows the issue or solution please tell me.Thanks in Advance .

Comment: I assume that by _"normal speaker"_ you mean the earpiece, i.e. the small speaker located above the screen, which normally is used for voice calls in handset mode. Which device are you testing this on? To me it sounds almost like a routing implementation bug by the manufacturer (not rerouting an ongoing `MUSIC` stream when the phone state changes from `IN_CALL` to `NORMAL`), but it's hard to say with the information available.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for replying .I am testing on MOTOROLLA MOTO E.And it is not that manufacturer bug as it is re routing ongoing  music but issue is that the voice come for earpiece rather than speaker .

Comment: Well, that sounds like it's _not_ rerouting the ongoing `MUSIC` stream when the call ends. That is, it's rerouting the stream to the earpiece when the call starts because `MUSIC` streams follows the same routing rules as voice calls when there's an active call, but then fails to route it back to the loudspeaker like it's supposed to (unless your app is doing something weird like calling `setPhoneState`).

Comment: @Michael And most strange thing is that it happens with my app only.And not with other voip apps installed in same device .